# In django form how to add checkboxes instead of radio button?

Tags: django, checkbox

I have a form where for one specific field I can have multiple choices. Something like

```
What would you like to eat this weekend?
Choice 1: Italian 
Choice 2: Mexican
Choice 3: Greek
Choice 4: Indian
```

I have radio button for all possible choices but because weekend is a multiple meals most of the time people want to select more than just one item. That makes me think it may be a good idea to have checkboxes associated with all possible choices.

How do I go about converting my radio buttons into a checkboxes ??

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to give more information. Is this a basic form, or a model form? Do you have a field that can accept multiple values?

Comment: Code to create Radio buttons
class MyForm2(forms.Form):
    MY_CHOICES = [ ('Maxical', 'Maxican'), ('Italian', 'Italian'), ('Indian', 'Indian'), ('Greek', 'Greek'),]
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=MY_CHOICES)
        def myfield_choices(self):
        field = self['myfield']
        widget = field.field.widget
        attrs = {}
        auto_id = field.auto_id
        if auto_id and 'id' not in widget.attrs:
            attrs['id'] = auto_id
        name = field.html_name
        return widget.get_renderer(name, field.value(), attrs=attrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MultipleChoiceField` in Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

If the choices that the user can select are coming from a model then you can use the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and pass a queryset for the choices. check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

Comment: Thanks I got it working. The solution was line below.

Comment: myfield = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=MY_CHOICES)

Answer (score 0):

Use the django [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#select)

```
CHOICES=[('Italian','Italian'),
         ('Mexican','Mexican')]

like = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select())
```

Comment: This line below creates a dropdown with all possible choices. I want all the options displayed with a box next to them so visitors can select what choices they prefer.